# swift uitableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: uitableview, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I am working on show weather project. I am listing the cities from database. When I click on a city, another viewcontroller should open. But when I click on a city, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function does not work.

Here is the my code:

```
class HavaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet var havatableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.havatableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
        havatableView.dataSource = self

        // XMl Parse
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://haberftp.trt.net.tr/haberservis/havadurumu.aspx")
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        if(data != nil){
        let dataxml = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(dataxml!)

        for merkez in xml["HavaTahmini"]["Merkez"] {
            var cityName = merkez.element?.attributes["MerkezAdi"]
            for gun in merkez["Gun"] {
              //  println(gun.element?.attributes["Tarih"])
                var tarih = gun.element?.attributes["Tarih"]
                var endusuk = gun["EnDusuk"].element?.text
                var enyuksek = gun["EnYuksek"].element?.text
                var durum = gun["DurumuKod"].element?.text


            }
        }


        }

     self.loadData()





        println("hava")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func newCityWeather(cityName: String, tarih: String, endusuk: String, enyuksek: String, durum: String){

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate )
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var newCity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Hava", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject


        newCity.setValue(cityName, forKey: "sehir")
        newCity.setValue(tarih, forKey: "tarih")
        newCity.setValue(endusuk, forKey: "endusuk")
        newCity.setValue(endusuk, forKey: "enyuksek")
        newCity.setValue(endusuk, forKey: "endusuk")
        newCity.setValue(endusuk, forKey: "durum")

        context.save(nil)

        //  println(newCity)


    }
    func newCity(cityName: String){

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate )
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var newCity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Sehirler", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject


        newCity.setValue(cityName, forKey: "sehir")
        context.save(nil)



    }
    func loadData() {
        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate )
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!


        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sehirler")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        if results.count>0 {

            for res in results {
            //    println(res)
            }

        }else {
            println("sonuc yok")

        }


    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 81
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell : HavaTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell") as HavaTableViewCell
        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate )
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!


        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sehirler")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        if results.count>0 {
            var cities = [String]()

            for result in results {
                 var res = result as NSManagedObject
                let city = res.valueForKey("sehir") as String
                cities.append("\(city)")
            }

            cell.setCell(cities[indexPath.row])


        }




        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      println("click")
        println(indexPath.row)
     //   performSegueWithIdentifier("showHavaDetay", sender: self)
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this:

```
havatableView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when compared two identical code examples where one was working and the other was not calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

There are at least two ways to solve the issue:

1) In the code itself:

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self 
//data source might be already set if you see contents of the cells
//the main trick is to set delegate
}
```

2) Using Storyboard or Document Outline (which was the problem in my case cause storyboard changes are not visible in .swift controller classes.

Open Document Outline and `Control + Press` your `TableView`
you will see two outlets called "`delegate`" and "`dataSource`"
drag them 1 by 1 to the containing `ViewController` (right onto the yellow circle)

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `delegate` property of the `UITableView` to get the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function to fire. Just declaring the class as supporting the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol is not enough.

```
havatableView.delegate = self
```

Setting the delegate to self tells the `UITableView` that the current class has the functions in the `UITableViewDelegate`

For more information : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/delegate